# Error uploading to QGIS Cloud

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am getting the following error when attempting to upload data to QGISCLoud using QGIS 3.10:

```
local variable 'hexstr' referenced before assignment
```

Has anyone seen this before and able to point me in the right direction?

Full error log below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Frank/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 975, in upload_data
    self.data_upload.upload(self.db_connections.db(unicode(db_name)), data_sources_items, unicode(self.maxSize))
  File "C:/Users/Frank/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\data_upload.py", line 254, in upload
    RasterUpload(conn,  cursor,  raster_to_upload,  maxSize,  self.progress_label)
  File "C:/Users/Frank/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\raster\raster_upload.py", line 113, in __init__
    gt = self.wkblify_raster(opts,  infile.replace( '\\', '/') , i, gt)
  File "C:/Users/Frank/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\raster\raster_upload.py", line 720, in wkblify_raster
    summary = self.wkblify_raster_level(options, ds, options['overview_level'], band_range, infile, i)
  File "C:/Users/Frank/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\raster\raster_upload.py", line 666, in wkblify_raster_level
    hexwkb += self.wkblify_band_header(options, band)
  File "C:/Users/Frank/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\raster\raster_upload.py", line 561, in wkblify_band_header
    hexwkb += self.wkblify(self.pt2fmt(pixtype), nodata)
  File "C:/Users/Frank/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\raster\raster_upload.py", line 494, in wkblify
    return hexstr
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hexstr' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Thanks @user2856, issue raised on github